# Is it possible for a family tree to contain a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

By family tree I mean the graph of humans which have ever lived, where there is an edge between parent and child.

Is it possible for a family tree to contain a cycle? I'm thinking not, but I don't know how to prove this. Are there any other interesting graphical properties about family trees?

Comment: As a directed graph, it seems unlikely without a time machine, but as an undirected graph, you can certain have cousins marrying.

Comment: There is a supposition that all humans have evolved from a common ancestor, called Eve.  If that's true, everyone is part of a cycle:  take the two paths from your parents to Eve.  Along with your edges to your parents, that makes a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

If you define an edge between a married couple, definitely you can have a cycle. For example, if a father marry his daughter.

If you have a tree of a species with one parent per child (asexual reproduction), than by definition you can't have a cycle because any directed edge between vertices (A-->B) means that A existed *before* B.

Following this causality leads to the impossibility of a cycle.